# Modifies Dijkstra’s Algorithm to find the maximum cost path

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

In a DAG and all weights are larger than 0. Is it possible to use a max heap to get the maximum cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work. Consider

- (a)-4->(b)
- (a)-1->(c)
- (b)-2->(d)
- (c)-6->(d)

Looking for the max cost path from (a) to (d), the max heap will follow (a)-4->(b)-2->(d) and never explore the (a)-1->(c) edge.

See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/) for an alternative based on a topological sort.

Comment: but for dijkstra, it will also consider the path after exploring a - b - d since the algorithm stores all the node inside the queue first. Then the maximum path will be updated and we will get the correct solution?

Comment: In traditional shortest-path Dijkstra, the algorithm stops once the target node is visited for the first time. If you apply Dijkstra but simply change min to max heap, the algorithm will terminate once you visit (d), but you will not (necessarily) find the max cost path.